# How can I generate cryptographically strong random strings with a given length

Tags: c#, random

I need to generate cryptographically strong random alphanumeric strings with a specified length, only using the following characters.

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9

Is there a way to accomplish this in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by cryptographically strong

Comment: @PeterSmith Most of the examples I read used Random class and some people had recommended using Cryptographic classes unless we use these strings as unique identifiers.

Comment: If you can live with just 0-9 and A-F (or a-f), you can just call `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes` and take the result and convert it to a hex string using one of the many methods described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`class RandomNumberGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-7.0) to generate cryptographically-secure random numbers to do this, for example:

```
string allowed = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMONOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmonopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
int strlen = 10; // Or whatever
char[] randomChars = new char[strlen];

for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++)
{
    randomChars[i] = allowed[RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0, allowed.Length)];
}

string result = new string(randomChars);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score -5):

Try following :

```
            int randomArrayLength = 256;
            char[] characters = {
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

            int numberOfChar = characters.Length;

            Random rand = new Random();
            string results = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, randomArrayLength).Select(x => characters[rand.Next(numberOfChar)]));
```

Comment: `Random` is [not cryptographically strong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0#remarks), as OP asked for.

Comment: @Magnetron : I assume the string is just a seed into a crypto generator.